# Android Studio shows black screen when running

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem when running the applications in Android Studio as everytime it shows only a black screen where it's written Android and that's all. Any ideas why it's doing this and how I can solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to SDK Manager->Extra->intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) and check is it installed or not? if it is not installed then install it.

2) Allow Virtualization in BIOS setting.

But i suggest you to use GenyMotion to run your Android Application. Here is link [https://www.genymotion.com]. It is FAST,SIMPLE and POWERFUL.

Comment: had you used Genymotion?

Answer (score 0):

When the emulator isn't booting it's mostly a driver problem.

Make sure you have all your windows updates, since windows by default also updates essential drivers. This happenes more often when you have an illegal version of windows.

Or download driver software that automatically updates your drivers.

Also downloading the "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio"'s worked for me, but I did not try this whithout my full update.